# Ninject + MVC3 + Medium Trust Environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, medium-trust

Ok, read a lot of questions about this, but really didn't see any solution that works for me... So, any help will be very apreciated.

I'm running a MVC3 web application with Ninject installed through nuGet (so i got Ninject version 3.0.1.10). Everything works great, except for when i deploy it to the hosting service (LocaWeb.com.br).

Running the web App from there, i got the "System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed."

And the stack trace shows lots of ninject's calls.

So i read somewhere that i should be using a Medium Trust Ninject version, wich I downloaded (ver 3.0.0.15 for Medium Trust) but i really don't have a clue on how to install it manually over the nuGet installed version, or even if this is the right path to go for solving the problem...

Really lost here. :-/

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something.. but can't you just remove your current Ninject references and install the required Ninject version through Nuget? All NuGet is doing is adding references for you (and downloading them).

Comment: Simon, I'm with you on that line of thought... But, unfortunatelly thare's no Ninject for medium trust environments available in NuGet :(  So, apperently i'm going to have to learn how to manually install this version which is available for download at the Ninject website.

Comment: Again though, theyre just project references.. Ninject is one of the easiest libraries to setup. Its literally 1 DLL and a specific extension DLL (in your case, probably Ninject.Web.Mvc).

Comment: I wish i could do it like this... But it's not working... :/  I've tried to override the NuGet DLLs & XMLs, but when you build the solution, they're overwritten back to the NuGet version. Til now, i discover that there's a folder named "bin" that holds those DLLs and XMLs, but there's another folder named "Packages", in which there's another copy of them. And in this last one, there's still a XML that indicates the packages and their versions (and the Ninject is listed there with the NuGet version)... There must be a strait-forward way of installing it manually...

Comment: Surprisingly there's no installation notes of any kink (or at least that I could find) in the Ninject website...

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the Ninject.dll from NuGet with the Medium trust dll when you deploy your application.